# Open telegram application from browser

Tags: browser, telegram

We have created a Telegram bot and we want start it by link for example

https://telegram.me/testbot?start=hello

When we write that link in browser automatically telegram application opens by value of start but we want to start telegram application by our site for example when user enter http://example.com/testbot?start=hello telegram application must starts with start value .

So have you any idea how can I do that ?

Answer (score 5):

if you already have the user's username (not all of them have one), you can use https://t.me/**USERNAME** and it should open the app.

Comment: in my case it was `tg://t.me/USERNAME`

Answer (score 0):

Telegram application does not listen to unknown urls. But as a workaround solution you can have a redirection in your landing pages.